# windows service- Not able to write files to azure file storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have mapped Azure file storage to my VM drive (T:).

Have windows service - which writes file in to mapped drive (T:). When I run this Windows service as a console application from command-line (with administrator mode), it writes the file to mapped directory. But it fails as a Windows service.

I've tried to Google this issue and got a suggestion: create a local user with the name as "Storage Account Name" and the password as "Account key", and use this user to run the Windows service. However, this didn't work.

Comment: set the service to run as the same user as you run it from the console. If that fixes it then it is almost certainly permissions on the share, make sure you grant the local machine account write permission. The switch back to running as local machine account

Comment: Hi  Tagc, For windows service LOG ON - have created local user with Storage Account Name and account key as password & added Administrator group.  Still is not working.

Comment: windows services (regardless the user under which they run) are not allowed to work with mapped drives - this is by security design. Use UNC paths instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/services-and-redirected-drives